# What does these UML symbol means

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I was going through UML class diagram in the class attributes what does the below symbol means?

~ package (default)
/ derived

I tried to search but didn't get much clue.Could any one tell me what these symbols means?

Answer (score 4):

As per definition

> **package (~)**
>
> A NamedElement with package visibility is visible to all
>   Elements within the nearest enclosing Package (given that other owning
>   Elements have proper visibility). Outside the nearest enclosing
>   Package, a NamedElement marked as having package visibility is not
>   visible. Only NamedElements that are not owned by Packages can be
>   marked as having package visibility.

Which means all elements in the same package have access to an element with package visibility while elements outside the package cannot access it.

> **derived (/)**
>
> If a Property has isDerived = true, it is derived and its value or
>   values may be computed from other information. Actions involving a
>   derived Property behave the same as for a nonderived Property. Derived
>   Properties are often specified to be read-only (i.e., clients may not
>   directly change values). But where a derived Property is changeable,
>   an implementation is expected to make appropriate changes to the model
>   in order for all the constraints to be met, in particular the
>   derivation constraint for the derived Property. The derivation for a
>   derived Property may be specified by a constraint.

Which means the property is not represented as such in the element, but rather comes as a result of some calculation. It is important though from the perspective of a model e.g. if you have on attribute for a *father* and one attribute for a *mother* you know who *parents* are. But sometimes you're more interested in an attribute *parent*. Thus *parent* would be derived.